# Avoiding Bitcoin Addresses Collisions

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, address-generation

Since every Bitcoin wallet can link multiple public keys / Bitcoin addresses to a single person, is there a mechanism in Bitcoin network to avoid 2 persons having the same Bitcoin address? Or it is achieved only by the space of possible keys/addresses (2^256 | 2^160)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, it is already answered there. My apologies.